# How install software that using old mysql, php version with newest LAMP version?

Tags: apache2, mysql, php

I try to install an old version of Invision Power Board (2.x) but when I want to configure database etc server return a blank white page
You can try here to understand what I mean
http://datatables.altervista.org/install/index.php

If I use a old old version of xampp (in this situation with windows) it works.
Is there is an workaround for newest LAMP version for ubuntu server?
You can take old version of IPB from [here](https://halflifex.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/IPB+2.3.6.rar) and test it but I think that you fail

Comment: While it’s certainly possible to do this with some recent versions of PHP and MySQL, there will be problems if you’re going too far back as many of the underlying libraries used in Apache and other tools have moved on. If the system does not need to be on the open web, perhaps you could run the system in a virtual machine with an older version of Ubuntu that supports the version of PHP and MySQL that you need.

Comment: @Matigo, I had a installed copy of software and a made a dump of database some years ago and then I save them as backups. Yesterday I try to copy-paste using FTP without install it and after I import my old database dump, I only change credentials into config files and it works. On my hosting I have newer version of PHP and MySQL installed, why in this situation it works? You can see an incompatible version to open web [here](http://nkj.altervista.org/)